# How do I access data in another contract/node?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design

I have two contracts - Data.sol and Buy.sol. Data.sol contains information on products, etc.

I want to use Buy.sol to get and update data in Data.sol, somewhat like having a database. I know this can be done externally on an Oracle if I'm not wrong, but I want the data to be transparent on the blockchain, if that makes sense.

Here's a snippet of what I've tried: Buy.sol has a function to update the buyers in Data.sol as well as to the get the data back. I deployed Data.sol on one wallet A, and Buy.sol on another wallet B. I run the buy function on wallet B and I want to get the buyers when I run the getBuyers function on wallet A. But right now, buy function affects the buyers mapping in wallet B but not A.

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong or deploying something wrong especially since this is my first solidity contract, so do advise! Thank you!

**Data.sol**

```
contract Data {

    // Create Product Object
    struct Product {
        string name;
        uint price;
        uint discount_factor;
    }
    
    uint numProducts;
    
    // Create Product Hashmap that maps product ID to Product
    mapping (uint => Product) public ProductsList;
   
    // Create Hashmap of Product Id to List of wallet addresses belonging to buyers of the product
    mapping (uint => address payable[]) public buyers;

    function getProductPrice(uint prodId) public returns (uint) {
        return ProductsList[prodId].price;
    }
    
    function updateProduct(uint prodId, address payable b) public {
        buyers[prodId].push(b);
        
        Product storage product = ProductsList[prodId];
        uint numBuyers = buyers[prodId].length;
        
        product.price = product.price - numBuyers * product.discount_factor;
    }

}
```

**Buy.sol**

```
import "./Data.sol"
contract Buy {
    Data d = Data(0xddaA.....76a75482d);

    // Buy item by adding buyer address to hashMap with key product Id
    function buy(uint prodId, address payable add) payable public  {
        d.updateProduct(prodId, msg.sender);
    }
    
    function getBuyers(uint prodId) public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return d.getBuyers(prodId);
    }
}
```

If it helps, I'm using pragma solidity ^0.6.0

Comment: Hi! I'm not fully understanding what you expect to see as the output of getBuyers, and what you're seeing instead - could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Hi @LinumLabs! getBuyers is supposed to return a list of addresses of people who bought the product according to the productId given! the buy function will add the msg.sender's address into the list. So my hope is that running getBuyers in wallet B using Buy.sol will give me the list of addresses from wallet A's buyers mapping if that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: That does make sense. It sounded like something else is happening instead (when you use address A to call getBuyers - what happens?

Comment: @LinumLabs if I use getBuyers on address A, I get an empty list. I assume it might be because I'm creating a new instance of Data() in address B, but I'm not sure how else to import Data.sol into Buy.sol!